# Going through a list in Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have a drop down menu. I want capybara to go through it and find the specific element and click on it. I'm currently trying to do a within clause and having it iterate through the list and find this element: "Cow_poop"

```
<li role="option" unselectable="on" title="Cow_poop" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-selected" aria-selected="true" style="user-select: none;">Cow_pop</li>
```

This is the code that I'm trying to do.

```
find('div.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-selected', text: 'Cow_poop').click
```

However it's giving me this error:

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "div.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-selected"
```

Comment: If the existing answer isn't providing what you want, please update your question to clarify your issue and include the HTML for the full menu you're trying to work with rather than just a single `li` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a `<div>` but a `<li>` element.

Your effective line of code will be:

```
find('li.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-selected', title: 'Cow_poop').click
```

Alternative:

```
find('li.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-selected[title=Cow_poop]').click
```

Comment: Thanks it's still unable to find the specific element. 
Unable to find css "li.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-selected"

Comment: Generally the decendant `<li>` elements are grouped within a `<ul>` element. In these cases you eed to click on some other desired element to expand the `<li>` elements and use this line to click on the desired `<li>`

Comment: So the element that I'll be clicking will be in a <ul> element.

Comment: In majority of the cased the the desired element is either a `<span>` or an `<input>`, but never a `<ul>` which you need to click to expand the `<li>`s.

Comment: The element you pasted above has the text "Cow_pop" not poop (and if that wasn't a copy/paste then it should have been for an SO question ;)

Comment: @Rubyman543 _`Cow_poop`_ isn't the _text_ but the `title` attribute. Can you retest the updated answer?